# Android color status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I would like to change color of my status bar. But everything I have tried didnt work.

values

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

values-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    </style>
```

manifest

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: on which os version you are trying it.?

Comment: @stepan extend your activity with AppCompatActivity and remove <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> only <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> would color your status bar

Comment: I am using an emulator, Android version is 6. But nothing you mentioned does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement it from java if you're using lower then 21st API in you application, just try the following code to change your status bar's color

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

one more thing, this code will not work if you extending AppCompatActivity in your activity, it will work only with Extends Activity